# Kafka Debezium connect to Oracle

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, oracle19c

So, I have Oracle DB 19c and try to connect to Kafka (with Debezium) on another server.
I already have DB, connector - which one dont work correctly

```
{
    "name": "ag-test3",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "alt-ads-d3.domain.corp:8083"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "state": "FAILED",
            "worker_id": "alt-ads-d3.domain.corp:8083",
            "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:67)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.oracle.xstream.XstreamStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(XstreamStreamingChangeEventSource.java:144)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.oracle.xstream.XstreamStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(XstreamStreamingChangeEventSource.java:45)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:205)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.
```

And thats i take from kafka-connector log:

```
[2023-08-22 19:02:05,300] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=ag-test3-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:190)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:67)
        at io.debezium.connector.oracle.xstream.XstreamStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(XstreamStreamingChangeEventSource.java:144)
        at io.debezium.connector.oracle.xstream.XstreamStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(XstreamStreamingChangeEventSource.java:45)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:205)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:172)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:118)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: oracle.streams.StreamsException: Oracle XStreamOut: failed to attach to XStream outbound server(dbzxout)

        at oracle.streams.XStreamOut.attachInternal(XStreamOut.java:386)
        at oracle.streams.XStreamOut.attach(XStreamOut.java:343)
        at io.debezium.connector.oracle.xstream.XstreamStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(XstreamStreamingChangeEventSource.java:119)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Unsupported feature: getOCIHandles
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getOCIHandles(PhysicalConnection.java:6559)
        at oracle.streams.XStreamOut.attachInternal(XStreamOut.java:367)
        ... 11 more
```

Please, i really need help =(

Unfortunately, I need to use XStream. I give all privileges to user.

Thats, how i create connector :

```
{
  "name": "ag-test3",
  "auto.create.topics.enable": "true",
  "config.action.reload": "restart",
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
  "database.connection.adapter": "xstream",
  "database.dbname": "ponpd",
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "***",
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "testagdebezium.oracle6",
  "database.hostname": "***",
  "database.out.server.name": "dbzxout",
  "database.password": "***",
  "database.port": "1521",
  "database.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.33.94)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ponpd)))",
  "database.user": "dbzuser",
  "errors.log.enable": "true",
  "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
  "errors.retry.delay.max.ms": "60000",
  "errors.retry.timeout": "0",
  "errors.tolerance": "none",
  "include.schema.changes": "true",
  "include.schema.comments": "true",
  "internal.snapshot.scan.all.columns.force": "true",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "***",
  "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
  "snapshot.mode": "always",
  "table.include.list": "customers",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "topic.prefix": "testagdebezium.oracle6",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
}
```